# #<NoMethodError: undefined method `token?' for #<User: >

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

When I try to create a user,I am facing this error

```
"exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `token?' for #<User:0x000056037eec27a0>>",
```

The db of the user is

```
 class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :phone
      t.string :token
      t.string :password_digest
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, unique: true
  end
end
```

My code for user model is

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_token
has_secure_password
has_many :projects , dependent: :destroy
end
```

My controller code is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def user_params
      Rails.logger.info "#{params.inspect}"
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :password)
    end
end
```

The data I am sending through the POST request is

```
{  
"user":{
      "name":"pranesh",
      "email":"pranesh@gmail.com",
      "phone":"987654321",
      "password":"helloworld"
      }
}
```

When I send the request,I am facing this error,

```
 "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `token?' for #<User:0x000056037eec27a0>>",
```

I am using rails `5.2.1`

Comment: If token column exists, try send("#{token}?")

Comment: Nope,token column does not exist

Comment: So check `User.columns` in rails console. It must contain `token`, if not then migration issue I guess!

Comment: @indrapranesh share your controller code

Comment: @NirajKaushal ,I have updated the question with my controller code

Answer (score 0):

`has_secure_token :token`

Try this

Comment: If possible drop the db and re-run the migrations. In user's table are you able to view the `token` column? check via mysql / postgresql command line